# How to access text files at synthesis level

Tags: verilog, fpga, lattice-diamond

I am writing Verilog code using Lattice Diamond for synthesis.

I have binary data in a text file which I want to use as input for my code.

At simulation level we can use **$readmemb** function to do it. How is this done at synthesis level?

I want to access data present in text file as an input for FPGA.

As suggested by Mr Martin Thompson(answers below) I have written a Verilog code to read data from a file.

Verilog code is given below:-

```
module rom(clock,reset,o0);
 input clock,reset;
 output o0;
 reg ROM [0:0];
 reg o0;
 initial
  $readmemb("rom.txt",ROM);
 always @(negedge clock,negedge reset )
   begin
if(reset==0)
    begin
    o0<=0;
    end
else
    begin
    o0<=ROM[0];
    end
  end
endmodule
```

When I am running this code on fpga I am facing the problem below:-

If text file which I want to read have only one bit which is '1' then I am able to assign input output pins to clock,reset and ROM. But if I have one bit which is '0' or more than one bits data in text file I am unable to assign input pins(i.e clock,reset) and a warning is displayed:-

```
 WARNING: IO buffer missing for top level port clock...logic will be discarded.
 WARNING: IO buffer missing for top level port reset...logic will be discarded.
```

I am unable to understand why I am getting this warning and how I can resolve it.

Comment: You now have a different problem, which deserves a different question (SO is not a discussion board).  Please revert your edits and raise a new question with the new problem in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to build the data into the netlist that you have synthesised.  You can initialise a read-only memory (ROM) with the data using `$readmemb` and then access that as a normal memory from within your device.

Here's an introduction to some memory initialisation methods:

http://myfpgablog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/memory-initialization-methods.html

And in here:

http://rijndael.ece.vt.edu/schaum/slides/ddii/lecture16.pdf

is an example of a file-initialised RAM on the second to last slide.  If you want just a ROM, leave out the `if (we)` part.

Comment: By using function **$readmemb** we can initialize a variable. How I can initialize ROM through it, how I would know data accessed is stored in ROM and what is its address?

Comment: According to the document suggested by you, it is written  **Synthesis tools will read hex file to initialize memory**. I am confused **$readmemh** is unsynthesisable function, how synthesis tool will synthesise **$readmemh** and read hex file?

Comment: `$readmem` is synthesisable as long as it is only called at elaboration time - in the "initial" stages.  During this stage, the synthesiser has the full resources of your PC to figure out what should go into the final netlist.  You *can't* call `$readmem` in the "running" part of your code  - in an `always` block for instance

Comment: As you have suggested Verilog code for ROM, I have updated it in my question and I am facing some problem while implementing it on FPGA(updated in question). Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Think of Simulation as an environment not a level. You should just be switching the DUT (Device Under Test) from the RTL code to the synthesised netlist, other than this nothing should change in your simulation environment.

From the block of code you have given it does not look like you are separating out the test and code for the fpga. You should not be trying to synthesise your test I would recommend splitting it between at least 2 separate modules, your test instantiating the code you want to place on the fpga. Pretty sure the `$fwrite` is also not synthesizable.

A simple test case might look like:

```
module testcase
  //Variables here
  reg reg_to_drive_data;

  thing_to_test DUT (
    .input_ports ( reg_to_drive_data )
    .output_ports ()
    ...
  ); 

  //Test
  initial begin
    #1ns;
    reg_to_drive_data = 0;
    ...
  end
endmodule
```

Via `includes`, `incdir` or file lists the code for thing_to_test (DUT) is being pulled in to the simulation, change this to point to the synthesised version.

If what you are trying to do is initialise a ROM, and hold this data in a synthesised design Martin Thompson's answer covers the correct usage of `$readmemb` for this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As I am beginner in Verilog, will you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: I am unable to interpret what exactly you are asking?

Comment: I am using Modelsim simulator, during simulation I am getting correct output. But at synthesis level, **$readmemb** function is not synthesizable, so what is the alternative for it at synthesis level

Comment: @SaadRafey now the Question and answers have been updated, could you please delete these comments to keep the site clean.